# Finding average temperature of cities (element can appear multiple times)

Tags: java, average

I've been having issues with this specific problem in Java. I'm stuck!
We ask from the user to enter number of data & then enter the temperatures and the names of the cities respectively. 
It is said though that the user might enter multiple temperatures for a specific city, for example:
Vienna 23 (in C)
Berlin 12
Paris 15
Berlin 9
Berlin 10
Paris 10

in no specific order. I've done this part with two 1D arrays but then the program asks that we calculate the average temperature of every city, the highest and the minimum temperature (obviously the min/max/avg will be the same if we only have one temperature of a city).

I don't know how I should do this part considering I have to go through the cities array and check how many times a specific city is listed there and then find the respective temperatures to find the average/min/max.
I have the concept but I can't make it in Java. Any thoughts/suggestions?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Create a map from cities to list of temperatures, then use this new data structure to perform your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `Data Structure`. Using two different arrays for attributes that are related is not a good idea.

Rather, maintain a mapping between city, and all its temperature. You would need to create a `Map` like this: -

```
Map<String, List<Double>> temperatureMap = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
```

Then for each city, you can easily calculate the average using the `List<Double>` for each of them.

Comment: @DNA.. OOPs.. Sorry for that. Next time I would wait few seconds before posting my answer. ;)

Comment: That's very kind indeed, much appreciated ;-)

Comment: Oh thank you for your quick answer however we haven't learned how to create 'Maps' yet so I can't use it. Is there anything simplier (more java basics) I could do?

Comment: @user1851084.. Trust me, this will be the best solution for your requirement. And you will see how much simple this is, as you move on with it. You can always learn on your own.

Comment: @user1851084.. And to create a `Map`, I have posted the code for you. And to add something to it, I'll add if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 Map<City,List<Temprature>>();
```

here is an example:

```
public class Temp {
Map<String,List<Double>> temp;

public Temp() {
    this.temp = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
}

private void insertTemperature(String city, double t) {

    if (temp.containsKey(city)) {
        List<Double> list = temp.get(city);
        list.add(t);
    } else {
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
        list.add(t);
        temp.put(city,list);
    }
}


private double calcAVG(String city) {
    List<Double> t = temp.get(city);
    double ttSum = 0;
    for (Double tt : t) {
        ttSum += tt;
    }

    return ttSum/t.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Please, if you are giving away the whole code, which you should not for some question that seems like homework. Also add some explanation to it. Else it won't help much.

Comment: In fact as it stands, that code will not compile. Type `City` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks Ahiel & RohitJain. I'm going to contact my teacher & ask him if I'm allowed to use Map/Lists. Very helpful! And @RohitJain, don't worry - this is only one small part of the assignment, I've still got a long way to go to complete it hehe ;]

Comment: @user1851084.. Well, you're welcome :). And yeah you might need to do some more work, but generally, we on SO, don't give away straight code, unless askers have tried something. This might give an impression on Posters, that they can get their homework done here.

Comment: However do you know any other possible way of solving this without using map? if it's technically possible anyway.

Comment: @user1851084.. Well, there are always more than one way to do something. You just need to find the best one. So, another way would be to create a class with attributes - `City`, and `List of temperature`, and use an array of that class type.